# Connect to remote CSV using hsqldb and java

Tags: java, hsqldb

I want to connect to a remote CSV using hsqldb and convert it to a TEXT table . Can anyone guide me with the steps that needed to be followed ? My code :

```
String url1 = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:197.161.16.16//data10//projects//2//hsqldb";
long currMilli = System.currentTimeMillis();
String tableName = "MRx" + currMilli;
final StringBuilder createTable = new StringBuilder();
final StringBuilder setDatabase = new StringBuilder();
setDatabase.append("SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE ");
createTable.append("CREATE TEXT TABLE" + " " + tableName);
createTable.append(columnNames);
final StringBuilder linkTable = new StringBuilder();
linkTable.append("SET TABLE" + " " + tableName + " SOURCE ");
linkTable.append("\"/" + "some.csv");
linkTable.append(";ignore_first=true;all_quoted=true;shutdown=true\"");
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url1, "sa", "");
    stm = conn.createStatement();
    stm.execute(createTable.toString());
    stm.execute(linkTable.toString());
    countResult = stm.executeQuery("Select count(*) from " + tableName);
    int totalCount = 0;
    while (countResult.next()) {
        totalCount = countResult.getInt(1);
    }
....................... // more code ...............
```

Even though the CSV has data , the `select` statement returns nothing . Whereas if I copy the same CSV to local system , and connect to it and read it , I can fetch the data ? Can anyone give any hint where I am going wrong !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a question of the path to your CSV file. Generally, HSQLDB treats the path as relative to the database files. It should work if the some.csv file is in the same folder as the databse files.

Note the `;shutdown=true` does not belong to a text table properties file. You could append it to the UR